# Why won't Team City load shoulda-matchers when it runs my tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm testing my rails app using rspec-rails and, especially for models, shoulda-matchers. The tests all run fine when I run them locally, but when I deploy to our Team City server, every test that uses shoulda-matchers fails because it can't find a method that should be provided by shoulda-matchers. For instance, one spec starts with:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Availability do
    it { should belong_to(:user) }
end
```

This spec fails with the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `belong_to' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_423:0x000000199a6348>
```

The way TeamCity runs the tests is slightly different, but I can't see how it would prevent this gem from being loaded.

Possibly related, my few capybara-webkit tests also fail with:

```
Capybara::DriverNotFoundError: no driver called :webkit was found, available drivers: :rack_test, :selenium
```

The shoulda-matchers, capybara, and capybara-webkit gems are all in my Gemfile in the 'test' group; rspec-rails is in the development and test groups.

Comment: Are you sure your test server is running in the test env and not development env? Try putting shoulda-matchers in the test/dev group

Comment: That was it, John. Thanks. Turn your comment into an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your test server is running in the test env and not development env? Try putting shoulda-matchers in the test/dev group